# Exclude __init__ parameters in sphinx autoclass output

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The output generated by the sphinx autoclass directive adds the parameters for __init__ to the end of the class name. Is there any way to tell sphinx to exclude them? I need to document classes that should not be explicitly constructed, so the __init__ parameters are an internal implementation detail that should be omitted from the docs

Answer (score 6):

To answer my own question, add () to the class name, e.g.

```
.. autoclass:: MyClass()
```

Comment: Doesn't work with sphinx-autodoc-typehints extension being enabled.